# Clear input field when checkbox unchecked from a checkboxList

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an ASP Webform website and one a page I have a `checkboxlist` which has an 'Other' option.  When the user checks this checkbox, an additional `textbox` is displayed. All this is working fine but the issue I am having is that, if the user unchecks the checkbox, it doesn't clear it.

The below code shows what I have

```
$(function ()
{
    $("input[name='ctl00$MainContent$Step04OtherField']").click(function ()
    {
        ToggleSection();
    });
        
    ToggleSection();
});
    
function ToggleSection()
    {    
        if ($("#MainContent_Browsers_5").is(":checked"))
        {
            $("#Step04OtherFieldDiv").show();
            document.getElementById("<%=reqStep04OtherFieldErrorMessage.ClientID%>").style.visibility = "visible";
            document.getElementById("<%=reqStep04OtherFieldErrorMessage.ClientID%>").enabled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            $("#Step04OtherFieldDiv").hide();
            $("#MainContent_Step04OtherField").val("");
            document.getElementById("<%=reqStep04OtherFieldErrorMessage.ClientID%>").style.visibility = "hidden";
            document.getElementById("<%=reqStep04OtherFieldErrorMessage.ClientID%>").enabled = false;
        }
    }
```

HTML for checkboxlist

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-offset-0 col-sm-offset-5 col-sm-2">
        <asp:CheckBoxList runat="server" id="Browsers" CssClass="CheckboxList">
            <asp:ListItem Text="All browsers" Value="All browsers"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="Internet explorer (IE)" Value="Internet explorer (IE)"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="Firefox (FF)" Value="Firefox (FF)"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="Chrome" Value="Chrome"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="Safari" Value="Safari"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="Other" Value="Other"></asp:ListItem>                
        </asp:CheckBoxList>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-offset-0 col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-8">
        <asp:CustomValidator Display="Dynamic" runat="server" ID="custBrowserCheckboxselected" ForeColor="Red" ErrorMessage="Please select at least one browser for us to check the website on." ClientValidationFunction="BrowserCheckbox_ClientValidate" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group" id="Step04OtherFieldDiv">
    <asp:Label ID="Step04OtherFieldLabel" class="col-sm-4 control-label" runat="server" Text="Please specify *" AssociatedControlID="Step04OtherField"></asp:Label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <asp:TextBox ID="Step04OtherField" runat="server" class="form-control" style="max-width: 100%" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="5"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-8">
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator Display="Dynamic" runat="server" ID="reqStep04OtherFieldErrorMessage" SetFocusOnError="true" ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="Step04OtherField" ErrorMessage="Please all browsers you would like the website checked on." />
    </div>
</div>
```

But the `$("#MainContent_Step04OtherField").val("")` doesn't seem to be working.

Also if there a better way of writing the above I'm up for that as I think it's a little messy but I couldn't get it working any other way; as it's a `checkboxlist` I could add individual ids to each one.

Comment: Can you post your HTML markup, so we can see how ``#MainContent_Step04OtherField`` is defined, please.

Comment: We need to see the HTML. Based on the script, I'd say that you should make sure to be binding the click on the checkbox (not on the textbox). Also, to "debug" jQuery selectors you can add `alert($("#MainContent_Step04OtherField").length);` or `alert($("#MainContent_Step04OtherField")[0].outerHTML);`

Comment: @user1438038 Full HTML markup added

Comment: @Diego Full HTML markup added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed using the below code

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    // Initially hide the 'Other' field row when page is loaded
    if ($("#MainContent_Browsers_5").is(":checked"))
    {
        $('#Step04OtherFieldDiv').show();
    }
    else
    {
        $('#Step04OtherFieldDiv').hide();
    }            

    $('#MainContent_Browsers_5').change(function ()
    {
        if (this.checked)
        {
            $('#Step04OtherFieldDiv').show();
            document.getElementById("<%=reqStep04OtherFieldErrorMessage.ClientID%>").style.visibility = "visible";
            document.getElementById("<%=reqStep04OtherFieldErrorMessage.ClientID%>").enabled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            $('#Step04OtherFieldDiv').hide();
            document.getElementById("<%=reqStep04OtherFieldErrorMessage.ClientID%>").style.visibility = "hidden";
            document.getElementById("<%=reqStep04OtherFieldErrorMessage.ClientID%>").enabled = false;
            $("#MainContent_Step04OtherField").val('');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are binding the `click` event to the `textbox` instead of the `checkbox`.

This code works:

```
$(function() {
    $("#chk").click(function() {
        ToggleSection();
    });

    ToggleSection();
});

function ToggleSection() {    
    var $txt = $("#txt"); // Save textbox's reference
    // The right way to check if a checkbox is checked is with .prop method
    if ($("#chk").prop("checked")) {
        $txt.prop("disabled", false);
    }
    else {
        $txt.prop("disabled", true).val("");
    }
}
```

[Test it here](http://jsfiddle.net/paska/3o7ztq8L/).

In the example I enable / disable the field so that you can see that the value is clear. [Here it is the code to show / hide](http://jsfiddle.net/paska/3o7ztq8L/3/):

```
var $chk;
$(function() {
    $("#checks :checkbox").each(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == "other")
            $chk = $(this);
    });
    $chk.click(function() {
        ToggleSection();
    });

    ToggleSection();
});

function ToggleSection() {    
    var $txt = $("#txt"); // Save textbox's reference
    // The right way to check if a checkbox is checked is with .prop method
    if ($chk.prop("checked")) {
        $txt.show();
    }
    else {
        alert("val: " + $txt.val());
        $txt.hide().val("");
        alert("val: " + $txt.val());
    }
}
```

Comment: I dont want to disable the field.  If you check my code snippets in my post, i am showing/hiding the field and if its displayed, then valiate if shown.

Comment: the issue i have is that the field is only displayed when the 'Other' checkbox is checked and as you cant add an id to checklist items the id is set on the top level of the checkboxlist so if i look at your code, if i change your `$("#chk")` to my checkboxlist id, wont it be displayed for any checkbox checked? hence why i am currently using `$("input[name='ctl00$MainContent$Step04OtherField']").click(function ()`

Comment: i have also updated my `if ($("#MainContent_Browsers_5").is(":checked"))` to `if ($("#MainContent_Browsers_5").prop(":checked"))`

Comment: It would be ugly but you could loop the checkboxes and when the value is the "other", save the reference and bind the event bind the event. Be careful with `.prop("checked")`, it is without the `:`

Comment: (check my answer once more)

Comment: Thanks for the help but i managed to resolve it as i have posted.